# Ruby Rails query selection criteria includes encrypted field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, conditional-statements, encryption

I am using Rails 2.3.4

I am looking less for a specific answer to this question, but more for general guidance in this matter.

In our (MySQL) database, we encrypt personally identifiable information (PII), such as name, address, phone number, etc. But I get requests for dynamic queries all the time.

For example, "Can you query the db to get me the entry values for a given date, but only for users in a list of area codes".

So, the selection criteria include some of the PII encrypted data, such as area code of their phone number.

For this discussion, the User and Entry tables have the following fields of interest:

User.id,User.phone

Entry.user_id,Entry.value,Entry.created_at

Because of encryption, I can't connect a SQL client and do my query the "easy" way to get all the entries on 11/21/2010 from users in a list of area codes (555,222,333), something like this:

SELECT E.value,SUBSTR(U.phone,2,3)
   FROM users U INNER JOIN entries E ON E.user_id = U.id
   WHERE DATE(E.sent_at) = '2010-11-21'
      AND SUBSTR(U.phone,2,3) in ('555','222','333')

I'd like to do in the console a query that might give me similar data.

It appears that the encrypted fields cannot be used as selection criteria, so I'm guessing that they are not decrypted until it is time to display them (rather than query them).

My brute force painful way was the following multi-step process:

1. select ALL the id's and area codes of ALL active users.
      User.all(:select => "id, phone",:conditions => ["state='active'"])
2. Do a screen grab of the terminal,
3. copy to a text editor, massage,
4. paste into excel,
5. use excel "filter" to grab user id's of only the desired area codes,
6. paste them into a flat file, massage into a comma-separated list, and then
7. paste into my SQL client to query by user_id
   SELECT * FROM entries WHERE user_id IN () and date(created_at) = ''.

"There's got to be a better way!" Any suggestions? Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

If you're using ActiveRecord, look at the attr_encrypted gem. It does a lot this for you.

The following sets up the encrypted attributes:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_encrypted :phone, :key => 'a secret key'
  attr_encrypted :password, :key => 'some other secret key'
end
```

And you can lookup and login users on the encrypted values like this:

```
User.find_by_email_and_password('test@example.com', 'testing')
```

https://github.com/shuber/attr_encrypted

Comment: Hi Jordan, Thanks for the reference. We don't store encryption keys in the code. That would enable anyone that had access to the db and the code to decrypt. We use PGP credentials, public/private key, etc. It seems to handle the decryption fine when I retrieve the record. (uu=User.find(23)) will return the entire User record, decrypted. But uu=User.find_by_phone('6065551212') will not find the user by phone number. That is, on the production server, where encryption is enabled, it won't find by phone number, but on dev, where encryption is not enabled, it finds it just fine.